# This variable was not recognized( NameError: name 'x_train1' is not defined)

Tags: python

I couldn't figure out the error though I tried some modifications and I tried downloading sklearn

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

And it didn't work :(
I need help a lot..

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-cd5d75bd5c5f> in <module>()
     24 model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
     25 
---> 26 x_train1 = np.array( x_train1).reshape(len( x_train1), -1)
     27 
     28 history = model.fit_generator(generator.flow(x_train1, y_train1, batch_size=64), epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=x_train1.shape[0]/64, 

NameError: name 'x_train1' is not defined
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import utils
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#import files 
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()


#load MNIST dataset 
def load_data():
    digits_data_train = pd.read_csv("mnist_train.csv")
    digits_data_test = pd.read_csv("mnist_test.csv")
    digits_data = pd.concat([digits_data_train, digits_data_test], 
    ignore_index=True)
 # Rename correct label column name to label
   digits_data.rename(columns={'0':'label'}, inplace=True)
 # Select 1000 samples from each class
   digits_data = digits_data.groupby('label').head(1000)
 # Split data into X and Y for each type
   Y1 = digits_data['label']
   X1 = digits_data.drop('label', axis=1)
 # Split data into X and Y for each type
   Y1 = digits_data['label']
   X1 = digits_data.drop('label', axis=1)
# Split data into train and test set
   x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(X1, Y1, 
   train_size=0.9)
# Convert into numpy array to ease preprocessing
   x_train1 = x_train1.to_numpy()
   x_test1 = x_test1.to_numpy()
# Convert Y into one-hot vectors
   y_train1 = to_categorical(y_train1, num_classes=36)
   y_test1 = to_categorical(y_test1, num_classes=36)
# Reshape Xs into CNN input dimension
   x_train1 = x_train1.reshape(x_train1.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
   x_test1 = x_test1.reshape(x_test1.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

  return x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1


def preprocessing(x_train1, x_test1):
    x_train1= x_train1 / 255
    x_test1= x_test1 / 255
    return x_train1, x_test1

x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = load_data()
(x_train1, x_test1) = preprocessing(x_train1, x_test1)

# Initialize Keras image generator
generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, zoom_range=0.1, 
width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1)


# CNN Model
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(28, 28, 1), 
    activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same", 
    activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.4),
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same", 
    activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.4),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Flatten(),
    Dropout(0.4),
    Dense(36, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", 
metrics=["accuracy"])


history = model.fit_generator(generator.flow(x_train1, y_train1, 
batch_size=64), epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=x_train1.shape[0]/64, 
validation_data=(x_test1, y_test1))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. The line in the traceback isn't in the code you've posted here. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: There's also a syntax error at `digits_data.rename`: `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: first use correct indentations in functions. With wrong indentations it gives different errors - and question make no sense.